# Understanding Arrow functions with an Example

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sudoku, arrow-functions

I'm having trouble understanding a solution to a coding challenge that uses arrow functions and the .every() method and was hoping someone more knowledgeable  could explain what's going on. The challenge is to check a grid to see if it represents a true sudoku board. I understand the first part concatenates and multiplies a row/col/square, but can't understand the latter part...

```
// True, if product of #s in row is 9!
p = a => eval(a.join("*")) == (1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9);

// Check each row, column and 3 block grid using p() 
sudoku = grid => 
  grid.every((r,i) =>
    p(r) &&
    p(grid.map(r => r[i])) &&
    p(r.map((_,j) => grid[3*(i/3|0)+(j/3|0)][3*(i%3)+(j%3)]) ) )
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Side note: the validation function isn't correct. Since it only checks the product of the collection, it'll fail on rows where (2, 4, 8) is replaced with (4, 4, 4) respectively (for example).

Comment: What do you refer to as the "latter part"? You already described what the second statement (the `sudoku` function) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems input data for sudoku is 2d array like this one:

```
let grid = [
  [2,4,1,7,6,8,5,3,9],
  [5,7,3,9,2,4,1,8,6],
  [8,9,6,5,3,1,7,4,2],
  [7,3,4,2,9,5,6,1,8],
  [1,8,9,4,7,6,3,2,5],
  [6,5,2,8,1,3,4,9,7],
  [4,6,5,3,8,2,9,7,1],
  [3,2,7,1,5,9,8,6,4],
  [9,1,8,6,4,7,2,5,3]
]
```

To validate Sudoku we have to check all rows, columns and sub-grids

[image: sub-grids explanation]

Code explanation:

```
p = a => eval(a.join("*")) == (1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9);
```

This is an equivalent for

```
p = function(a) {
  return eval(a.join("*")) == (1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9);
}
```

So function "p" gets array of integers

```
[2,4,1,7,6,8,5,3,9]
```

joins all integers with "*" and as a result we have:

```
"2*4*1*7*6*8*5*3*9"
```

then evaluates this string and as a result we have:

```
362880
```

This is the same value as `1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9`

So now we can check each row, each column and each sub-grid with this function.

```
sudoku = grid => 
  grid.every((r,i) =>
    validRows &&
    validColumns &&
    validSubGrids )
```

is the same as:

```
sudoku = function(grid) {
  grid.every( function(r, i) {
    return 
      validRows &&
      validColumns &&
      validSubGrids
  })
}
```

The `every` method executes the provided callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a falsy value. Otherwise it returns true.

Valid Sudoku means that our `every` function's callback returns `true` for all elements.

`p(r)` - validate each row

`p(grid.map(r => r[i]))` - validate each column

function `map` creates new array.
E.g. for `i=0` it will provide following result:

```
[ grid[0][0], grid[0][1], grid[0][2],...]
```

`p(r.map((_,j) => grid[3*(i/3|0)+(j/3|0)][3*(i%3)+(j%3)]) ) )` - validate each sub-grid

Code equivalent:

```
p(
  r.map( function(_,j) {
    let row = 3 * Math.floor(i/3) + Math.floor(j/3)
    let column = 3 * (i%3) + (j%3)
    return grid[row][column]
  })
)
```

So as a result we validated all rows, all columns and all sub-grids.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudoku = grid => 
  grid.every((r,i) =>
    p(r) &&
    p(grid.map(r => r[i])) &&
    p(r.map((_,j) => grid[3*(i/3|0)+(j/3|0)][3*(i%3)+(j%3)]) ) )
```

1. For every item r in grid, p(r) is evaluated. If its true then second part will be evaluated
2. `grid.map(r => r[i])` will be evaluated which in turn will iterate through all grid items and return an array of their **i**th element.

   Now after if `p(grid.map(r => r[i]))` is true then the latter part will be evaluated.
3. Finally `r.map((_,j) => grid[3*(i/3|0)+(j/3|0)][3*(i%3)+(j%3)]) )` will be executed but only if previous two conditions were true.
   This will also return an array of grid items, depending upon values of i & j.

> So key points here is the usage of **&&**

`A && B` will return B if A evaluates to true(and B will only be evaluated when A is true)

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, an arrow function is just a function. The only real different between the two is that `this` is preserved from the outer context when using an arrow function, whereas `this` is the `this` that was used to call the function with a normal function.

```js
function A() {
  this.v = 1;
  this.a = () => console.log(this.v);
  this.b = function () { console.log(this.v) };
}

// Both will use `obj` as `this`
const obj = new A();
obj.a();
obj.b();

// The arrow-function `a()` will keep the same `this` as above, `obj` will change.
const obj2 = { v: 2 };
obj2.a = obj.a;
obj2.b = obj.b;
obj2.a();
obj2.b();
```

The other difference which may be throwing you off, is with an arrow function, if it only needs one line, you can omit the curly brackets (`{}`) and it will return the value. I.e.,

```
a => 1
```

Is the same as:

```
function (a) { return 1; }
```

In this sample code, being an arrow function or a regular function would make no different, as `this` isn't being invoked.

What the code is doing is:

```
grid.every((r, i) =>
```

Look through every element in the `grid`, and keep going as long as it returns `true`. `r` is the current value of `grid` and `i` is the current index it is processing.

```
grid.map(r => r[i])
```

is literally just getting the `i-th` value from `r` and returning it. This would be for checking the diagonals of a two-dimensional array. (So it gets `grid[0][0]`, `grid[1][1]`, and so on).

```
r.map((_, j) => grid[math])
```

Is then just looping through each element in `r`, and getting some element (based on that math) using the current `i` index from the outer loop and the `j` index from `r`. Using `_` as a parameter name is a common convention to indicate that you just don't care about that parameter.